# EOF or blocking when dealing with the pipe

Tags: python, linux, operating-system, pipe

Usually, when creating pipes for IPC between parent and child processes, we immediately closed the read fd in parent process and write fd in the child process. I don't understand why the read behavior is different for parent if we don't close the child write fd.

**First case: (the write fd in child process is not closed)**,'Blocking' is never printed and the `os.read` is blocking indefinitely.

```
import os

r,w = os.pipe()
pid = os.fork()

if pid:
    print('parent %s'%pid)
else:
    print('child %s'%pid)
    # os.close(w) without this line, os.read would block
    num = os.read(r, 100)
    print('Blocking')
    print(num)
```

**Second case: (the write fd in child process is closed)**, 'Blocking' is printed and `EOF` is reached.

```
import os

r,w = os.pipe()
pid = os.fork()

if pid:
    print('parent %s'%pid)
else:
    print('child %s'%pid)
    os.close(w) 
    num = os.read(r, 100)
    print('Blocking')
    print(num)
```